# Where do I update sshd to read from another config file for second instance of ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

I followed the following steps in order to get a second instance of sshd running on my server: http://fixunix.com/ssh/364505-running-multiple-sshd-instances-one-server.html

The only problem is, I'm not sure where exactly I need to modify to get my new instance of sshd to read from /etc/ssh/newsshd_config. It continues to read from /etc/ssh/sshd_config which is obviously not my intention. my intention is to run with a brand new set of configs.

this is on a rhel box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of your sshd init script and append the -f option to specify the new sshd_config.